# How to debug a C++ library while developing an Android application?

Tags: android, c++

I am developing an Android application that requires the use of the ffmpeg (C++ library) which I need to modify. My primary development environment is Windows, and now I'm planning to compile this C++ library in a Linux virtual machine and provide it to the upper-level application. I intend to debug by printing log messages to inspect the debug information. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Android Studio let you put breakpoints and debug C++ code. You need of course to compile ffmpeg with symbols and preferably without optimisation for debugging.

Comment: Develop your core code as a standard C++ static lib, and unit test it properly (that way you will not need logging for that part). Any interaction with OS or filesystem should be handled by dependency injection (no direct OS or filesystem interaction). So yes there is a better approach, learn how to design for and use unit testing. (Logging has a tendency to slow down your normal production code)